# addAll() implementation -- Java

Tags: java, collections

**addAll()** of **AbstractCollection** is implemented as follows:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) { 
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c) if (add(e)) modified = true; 
    return modified;
}
```

So, if **c** in the parameter is a collection of, say 3 elements, it may be the case that first 2 
of these elements are added, but the 3rd isn't added for some reason i can't think of right now.

In this case, the **addAll()** operation-- the addition of all of these 3 elements to the underlying 
Collection isn't carried and **addAll()** is returning false as it should. However, the first 2 elements are there-- and the developer 
would expect they shouldn't be(?)

**HashSet** is using this **addAll()** in its constructor-with-a-single-param that is of type Collection.

So, the developer could end up with a **HashSet** instance 
that contains a part of his collection while he`s looking for the entire collection. And this happens without any warnings.

The methods involved--  **put()** of **HashMap** and **add()** of **HashSet** seem straightforward enough-- 
doesn`t seem anything can go wrong during these operations-- but still.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Nice, didn't know this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the developer could end up with a `HashSet` instance that contains a part of his collection while he`s looking for the entire collection. And this happens without any warnings.

Not true. The fact that `Set.add` returns `false` means that it was already there. The only exceptions to this would be bounded collections that have size limits, at which point the developer should know it's a bounded collection anyway and won't necessarily contain all the elements. For most collections in the collections API, calling `addAll` guarantees that `containsAll` will return `true` if you call it with the same collection. I.e. this will print `true`:

```
Set<T> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<T> set2 = new HashSet<>();
// Add stuff to the sets
set1.addAll(set2);
System.out.println(set1.containsAll(set2));
```

Comment: This restricts the exceptional cases to what youre saying in your answer and i can't think of anything else going wrong. However, a bit odd still that this isn't fully covered in its use in HashSet.

Answer (score 6):

The contract of `Collection#addAll(...)` merely says it returns `true` if the collection (this) is modified. It does not guarantee that the addition will be atomic or complete.

Answer (score 5):

> In this [not all elements being added] case, the addAll() operation-- the addition of all of these 3 elements to the underlying Collection isn't carried and addAll() is returning false as it should.

[`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) returns `true` if *any* of the elements of `c` were successfully added, *not* if they were *all* added. You can see this from the code you posted: `modified` is set to `true` *as soon as* an [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) call returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

As others already mentioned, the method returns `true` if any element is successfully added.

Additionally:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

So, given the implementation of `addAll` you presented, if an element is not added, and no exception is thrown, it's because the element was already in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) says that `addAll` returns `true` if the current `Collection` is modified (`false` otherwise).

This means that even if just one element gets added, the method will return `true`. Think of the returned value as an indicator of whether this collection was *modified* as a result of the method call and not that all elements were added.